# Depended variable Joint random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I'm having difficulties to understand how to approach to this question:

Rolling a dice for 2 times.

- X - Result of the first time.
- Y - The highest results from both of the rolls.

Example: if in the first we'll have 5, and in the second 2, Y will be 5.

1. Show that X and Y are depended
2. calculate (Cov(x,y))

can you assist me with that please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

the first question's intuition is, you have to show that if you know something about $X$, you will affect what $Y$ is, or vice versa. The simplest way to see this is, if $X$ is anything, $Y$ can be any number from 1 to 6. But if $X=6$, you know $Y=6$, so information about $X$ changes what you know about $Y$, hence they are dependent. You can (and should) make this formal with conditional probability.

As for the second question, it is pretty mechanical. Use that
$$
Cov(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}\left[ \left(X - \mathbb{E}[X]\right)
                            \left(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y]\right)\right]
$$

Feel free to post updates with your work on this problem as comments and I will be happy to give you further guidance. But I would like to see some of your own work proceeding from here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, clearly $\mathsf P(X=k)~=~\begin{cases}1/6 &:& k\in\Bbb N, 1\leq k\leq 6\\0&:&\textsf{otherwise}\end{cases}$

And $\mathsf P(Y=j\mid X=k) ~=~ \begin{cases}\underline{\phantom{k/6}} &:& j\in\Bbb N,k\in\Bbb N, 1\leq k=j\leq 6 \\ \underline{\phantom{1/6}} &:& j\in\Bbb N,k\in\Bbb N, 1\leq k<j\leq 6 \\ 0 &:& \textsf{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Even without working out exactly what are the pieces of that function, it is obvious that because it is certain that $X\leq Y$, therefore the two variables are dependent.   (If it is given that that $X=5$, then you know $Y=5$ or $Y=6$ with probabilities $5/6$ and $1/6$ respectively, et cetera.)

Fill in the blanks, then find $\mathsf E(Y\mid X)$, and use this to find $\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)$ $${\mathsf E(Y\mid X=k) ~=~ k~\mathsf P(Y=k\mid X=k)+\sum_{j=k+1}^6 j~\mathsf P(Y=j\mid X=k)\\~~~~~\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)~=~\mathsf E(X\mathsf E(Y\mid X))-\mathsf E(X)~\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))}$$